# how to run app from xcode on device?

Tags: ios, xcode

I had created my first iOS app with Xcode, but when I tried to export the file to run on an iPad I couldn't build the project. When I go to `products > file.app >`  and then right click to show on folder it is hidden.

How can I export the file to run on iOS devices?

Also if I have the project at my Windows PC can I export the app file to work on iOS devices ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run iOS apps on a device, you need to first have [a valid Apple Developer Account](https://developer.apple.com/register/index.action), and have your device setup as a valid [developer enabled device](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment.html).

Once that is done, you simply set your ipad as the target in Build Target. You may need to use the Organizer to first ensure you have the dev certs setup properly.

> Also if I have the project at my Windows PC can I export the app file to work on iOS devices ?

In order to build iOS apps, you need Mac OS X (and legally that can only run on an Apple computer)

Comment: As of 2015-09-29, it seems that Apple Developer Account is no longer essential to run app on devices.

From [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html), it said:

`You can launch your app on a device using a free Apple ID account, but the capabilities available to your app depends on the platform and your program membership, described in Supported Capabilities.`

Comment: Interesting. I need to run through this process, then update my answer. Good find!